# Unregister C2DM registration Id

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I want to un-register `C2DM` registration id. When I run the code below:

```
public void unregisterForC2DM() {
        Intent unregIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
        unregIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
        startService(unregIntent);
}
```

app should not get the message from third party server. But app is still getting messages from server. I have put all required permission in the manifest file.
Referred site : http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Comment: unregistering just send information to thrid party server that it should unregister this device ... so it depends on your server code

Comment: Thanks Selvin for the quick reply. Yes I have not cleared the registrationId from third party server. But is it not possible that the above code just invalidates Android device's current registrationId so that the third party server can not send the notification.

Comment: it depends on your implementation of onReceive method in your reciver registered for  `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` ... but usually our implementation just sending info to 3rd party server ... the same code is called by Android OS when it gets information from Google server that registration ID is expired

Comment: Thnx Selvin, The problem is I do not have any resource at server side to clear the registrationId. I have to invalidate/clear it from android side on C2DM Server so that when third party server communicates to C2DM Server it gets failed authentication using that registrationId to authorize itself.

Comment: i'm using this http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/browse/ as a base source of C2DM ... anyway ... are you sure that this registrationId belongs to your program ?  even if it's true you could also "unregister" this id on your server if sending message to C2DM google server fails (but first double check your auth code)

Comment: Yes. The registrationId belongs only to my application and you can verify it on http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#arch in "Credentials" table. I have to consider clearing registrationId at server as last option only when it is not possible from Android device side.