# push notification cannot unregister

Tags: android, push-notification

```
private void unregister() {
    Intent unregIntent = new Intent(
            "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
    unregIntent.putExtra("app",
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    startService(unregIntent);
}
```

I call this function but return to me

`com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` instead of `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTRATION`?

When i call `unregister()`, it run the

```
if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(action)) {
        final String registrationId = intent
                .getStringExtra("registration_id");
        String deviceId = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        sendRegistrationIdToServer(deviceId, registrationId);
        System.out.println(registrationId.toString());
        // createNotification(context, registrationId);
    }
```

This is my `androidmanifest.xml`, is there need to add an unregister?

```
<receiver
        android:name=".C2DM_RegistrationReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="oriental.orientalOnePaper" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".C2DM_MessageReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="oriental.orientalOnePaper" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: you want to stop receiving push notification messages? did u get any error from server

Comment: i had updated my code, the server i just use simple java server, so i cannot get the response

Comment: check  the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851589/unregister-c2dm-registration-id